# Laravel Seeding With Model Factories

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to figure out how I can seed my db with x number of posts however I actually want to have it seed the name of the post with "News Story X for each iteration in this instance. Meaning I want the first one to come out as "News Story 1 and the second as News Story 2, and so on.

Any thoughts on how I can accomplish this.

```
$posts = factory('App\Post', 3)->create();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `make`method instead of `create` to tweak the post before saving:

```php
factory('App\Post', 3)->make()->each(function ($post, $index) {
    $post->fill(['name' => 'News Story '.($index + 1)])->save();
});
```